# Igraph In R, issue in graph_from_data_frame

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I want to create a network in R, where the nodes are stored in papers and the edges are stores in citations. However, I am getting an error. I am new in this domain, some help from the experienced users would be appreciated.

*I want to present the citation relationship between papers*

Please visit the link to view complete project: https://github.com/virani1997/Information_Organization_Final_Project

[image]

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory: the edge list stores the relationship between nodes (vertex). Some of the nodes in the edge list are not found in the node list. For example, while the node list contains nodes from {1,2,3,4,5}, the edge list specifies an edge between nodes 5 and 6. This throws an error.

Comment: How do you suggest this problem can be solved? How can make a network graph that link the papers and the citations it has got?

Comment: From the error message, you need to ensure that every node mentioned in the edge list appears in the node list. You can filter the node list to check for that which may solve your issue. For your specific problem, it is likely that your edge list references documents outside of your corpus (which cannot be graphed, leading to an error).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, example:

```
citations <- cbind(from = c(1, 1, 2), to = c(2, 4, 6))
papers_in_citations <- unique(el)
papers              <- c(1,2,3)
```

Find orphans in papers and citations.

```
meet                <- intersect(papers_in_citations, papers)
orhans_in_citations <- setdiff(papers_in_citations, meet)
orphans_in_papers   <- setdiff(papers, meet)
```

Show the problems.

```
papers_in_citations
papers
orhans_in_citations
orphans_in_papers
```

Output.

```
papers_in_citations
[1] 1 2 4 6
papers
[1] 1 2 3
orhans_in_citations
[1] 4 6
orphans_in_papers
[1] 3
```

The next step is to sanitize your data.